# pkgdown fails parsing Rd files when examples are added

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2, pkgdown

for some reason `pkgdown` is failing to parse one of the .Rd files that I have in my package. I found it fails when I add examples to the `roxygen2` documentation using either the `@examples` tag or the `@example inst/example/add.R` alternative. I minimized my function to two arguments in order to make it more "reproducible" and still getting the same error. Please find bellow the error message, the .Rd file generated using that  `devtools::document()` and the roxygen2 documentation of the function. As you can see I am using a very simple example that should run with no problems... One more thing to say is that when I run `devtools::check()` all my examples pass, so I don't understand why `pkgdown` is failing.

Thank you so much for your help.

Best,

### Error message

```
Reading 'man/merge.Rd'
Error : Failed to parse Rd in merge.Rd
i unused argument (output_handler = evaluate::new_output_handler(value = pkgdown_print))
Error: callr subprocess failed: Failed to parse Rd in merge.Rd
i unused argument (output_handler = evaluate::new_output_handler(value = pkgdown_print))
```

### .Rd file

```
% Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/merge.R
\name{merge}
\alias{merge}
\title{Merge two tables}
\usage{
merge(x, y)
}
\arguments{
\item{x}{data frame: referred to \emph{left} in R terminology, or \emph{master} in
Stata terminology.}

\item{y}{data frame: referred to \emph{right} in R terminology, or \emph{using} in
Stata terminology.}
}
\value{
a data.table joining x and y.
}
\description{
This is the main and, basically, the only function in joyn.
}
\examples{
x <- c(1, 2)
}
```

### roxygen2 documentation

```r
#' Merge two tables
#'
#' This is the main and, basically, the only function in joyn.
#'
#' @param x data frame: referred to *left* in R terminology, or *master* in
#'   Stata terminology.
#' @param y data frame: referred to *right* in R terminology, or *using* in
#'   Stata terminology.
#' @return a data.table joining x and y.
#' @export
#' @import data.table
#'
#' @examples
#' x <- c(1, 2)
```

Comment: It looks as though you're using the development version of `pkgdown` from Github, but not corresponding versions of its dependencies.  Use CRAN versions unless you really need the devel version.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. I used CRAN version and it worked. However, it still giving some weird messages saying that something is not right, though I got a working page. In any case. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

This error comes from `downlit::evaluate_and_highlight` (sad it's not reported in the output), and can be fixed by installing the development version of `downlit`:

```
library(devtools)
install_github('r-lib/downlit')
```

It make sense only if you use the git version also from `pkgdown`, the stable `pkgdown` (version 1.6.1) runs just fine with the stable `downlit`. Of course development version of any package can break at any time, but until it doesn't, it's just alright.